Embedded coder output in C inquiry
This is line is always used in SIMULINK embedded coder .c file output :
#define MAX_int8_T                     ((int8_T)(127))

and it uses this line too :
typedef signed char int8_T;

I understand that it defined a new variable called (int8_T) to be (signed char) that stores values from
-128 to 127 = 256 number, but I don't understand the first code line, can I define a macro to be 2 values ? I always define macros to carry only one value like below :
#define x      100

That I fixed x to always equals 100, so does SIMULINK define MAX_int8_T  to equal (int8_T) or (127)
Or what did it do?
typedef signed char int8_T;

#define MAX_int8_T                     ((int8_T)(127))


Read up on typedef (it doesn't create a new variable) and casting.

@Shawn  ... and the purpose and behaviour of  preprocessor macros.


I understand that it defined a new variable called (int8_T) to be (signed char)

Your understanding is incorrect.  That line defines a type alias for signed char, not a variable.  It allows you to instantiate variables of type int8_T that are signed char, e.g.:
int8_T small_integer = MAX_int8_T ;


can I define a macro to be 2 values?

You can define macros to be anything you like, they are not on their own syntactically significant. Nonetheless, that (defined as two values) is not what is happening in this definition.  Macros are simply text replacements.  So the above instantiation after the preprocessor (which does the text replacement) runs looks to the compiler like:
int8_T small_integer = ((int8_T)(127)) ;

It is at that point that the code is parsed and the semantics and syntax of the macro definition are effective.
What is happening here is that the literal constant 127 on its own has type int and the (int8_T) is a type cast to explicitly convert it to int8_T before assigning it to the variable small_integer.  Without the type alias, it is equivalent to:
signed char small_integer = ((signed_char)(127)) ;

It is a bit weird of Simulink to create these definitions when there are standard definitions for this in <stdint.h> and <limits.h>, where you would write:
int8_t small_integer = SCHAR_MAX ;

I strongly recommend that you use the standard definitions in your own code.

Last excerpt should probably be "int8_t ..."

int8_t exists since C99. Simulink is quite a bit older than that. They should probably update their code, but few companies do unless the old code stops working as intended.

@CrisLuengo.  Who are you suggesting updates what?  While Simulink may have been a product since before C99 if has surely had updates since then and no one is using a 25 year old version?  It is possible that it is an attempt for broad compatibility with older compilers.  That is nonetheless why I suggested avoiding it in their own code (new, not legacy) as opposed to the generated code.

The line
#define MAX_int8_T                     ((int8_T)(127))

does not define a macro with two values. Instead, it is defining a value of 127 casted to the type int8_T.
Casting means changing the data type of a value to another type. This specific type of casting is called C-style casting and can be written as (data_type)value or (data_type)(value). In this case, the data_type is int8_T and value is 127.
Also note that the macro itself will not perform the casting. A macro is simply a preprocessor directive that replaces all of its occurrences with its defined text.
Secondly, the following line
typedef signed char int8_T;

does not create a variable named int8_T of type signed char. Instead, it defines an alias or an alternative name for the type signed char. Hence, the following lines of code will be equivalent.
signed char value1;
int8_T value1;

Lastly, you should not use the type int8_T in your own code. It appears that MATLAB may be generating its own types for some reason. When writing your own code, you should use standard fixed width integer types. Use int8_t instead of int8_T. These types are defined in a file called stdint.h and are available with every implementation.
